# jQuery event not firing when input is updating through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi everyone I have problem with firing jQuery event after ajax calls.
I have method which calculates prices based on two inputs:

- quantity
- unit_price

> ```
>    amount_calculation_when_unit_price_change = (parent) ->
>       $(".unit_price input").bind "keyup change paste", (e) ->
>       unit_price = @value.replace(/\,/g,'.')
>       quantity = $(this).closest(parent).find(".quantity input").val().replace(/\,/g,'.')
>       value = ((parseFloat(unit_price) * parseFloat(quantity)))
>       amount = $(this).closest(parent).find(".amount")
>       if value.toString().match(pricePattern)
>         amount.html('<br/>' + '$' + "#{(value.toFixed(2))}")
>       else
>         amount.html('<br/>' + '$' + "0.00")
>       calculate_total()
> ```

It works ok. But I also have an autocompletion feature through ajax. And when I autocomplete this inputs through ajax this code is not fired. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: To summarize of the other QA : use $(somecontainer).on("keyup change paste", ".unit_price input", function`

Comment: for autocomplete change use the event `autocompletechange`

Comment: I've changed this code:
$(".unit_price input").bind "keyup change paste", (e) ->
to this:
$("body").on "keyup change paste", ".unit_price input", ->
And its still not working.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański Can you make a fiddle reproducing your problem ?

Comment: I leave this feature beacuse it causes other problems in my application but thanks for help.